# Why does this code receive an error in test cases in codewars?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

I don't know why but I always receive an error when I run the following code:

```js
function list(names) {
  let str = '';
  if (!names) {
    return ''
  } else if (names.length == 2) {
    return names[0].name + ' & ' + names[1].name;
  } else if (names.length == 1) {
    return names[0].name;
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < (names.length - 2); i++) {
      str += names[i].name + ', ';
    }

    str += names[names.length - 2].name + ' & ' + names[names.length - 1].name;
    return str;
  }
}
```

with test cases in [codewars kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/53368a47e38700bd8300030d/train/javascript).
The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at list
    at /home/codewarrior/index.js:36:19
    at /runner/frameworks/javascript/cw-2.js:152:11
    at Promise._execute
```

`names` should be an array which can be empty and the array elements are objects with name properties.

Comment: Where does it even throw that error? What is the input?

Comment: Unlike python, in javascript an empty array is truthy, so `if(!names)` is not the right way to check for an empty list.

Comment: What if names.length is 0. Check for that too.

Comment: It is test cases, I will add the code.

Comment: Yeah, now I got it. @georg and Tushar Shafi are correct. Thanks ! 

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution, you can do with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

You have to encounter 2 corner cases:

**1)** An input array of zero-length
then you've to `return` empty string as

```
 if (!names.length) return "";
```

**2)** An input array of length one, then you have to just return the name as:

```
if (names.length === 1) return names[0].name;
```

```js
function list(names) {
  if (!names.length) return "";
  if (names.length === 1) return names[0].name;
  const namesStr = names.map((o) => o.name).join(", ");
  const index = namesStr.lastIndexOf(",");
  const result = namesStr.slice(0, index) + " &" + namesStr.slice(index + 1);
  return result;
}

const result = list([{ name: "Bart" }, { name: "Lisa" }, { name: "Maggie" }]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The kata mentions that you should return an empty string for an empty array. I think you intended to do that with

```js
if (!names) {
    return ''
  }
```

... but an empty array is still truthy. Perhaps that line should be `if (!names.length)`.

Comment: Btw, it's considered best practice in javascript to use strict comparison in evaluations, like `.length === 1`, since, e.g., `true == 1` is true